# Entropy, as state counting

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

In Roger Penrose's book "Cycles of Time, An Extrordinary New View of the Universe," in chapter 1.2 "Entropy, as state counting," the author illustrates the second law of thermodynamics with an example based on mixing colors in a jar.
The author idealizes the situation by imagining a cubic box with $N×N×N$ compartments, each occupied by a little ball (red or blue).
The individual compartments are also grouped into smaller cubic boxes ($n \times n \times n$, with $n \ll N$) for the purpose of judging the local uniformity of the purple color obtained after mixing the colors.

The author a little later concludes:

> "we find that, with these numbers ($N= 10^8$ and $k= 10^3$, so $n=10^5$) there are around $10^{23.570.000.000.000.000.000.000.000}$ different arrangements of the entire collection of $½N^3$ red balls and $½N^3$ blue balls that give the appearance of a uniform purple."

Immediately thereafter Penrose states

> "there are only a mere $10^{46.500.000.000.000}$ different arrangements which give the original configuration in which the blue is entirely
> at the top and the red entirely at the bottom."

Can anyone help me understand the combinatorics that leads to these results?

I realize that I did not express the problem correctly. I am really sorry.
To explain exactly the problem I include the 3 pages from Penrose's book.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please explain what $k$ means in the body of your question. I don't see where $k$ is defined.

Comment: by context $k^3$ is the number of particles that go in each box

Comment: @JohnA. If you are certain that is the case, then will you edit it into the question so that the question stands alone as  well defined?

Comment: Is the $k=10^3$ supposed to read $k^3 = 10^3$?

Comment: I don't have the book but it seems clear enough that (given the definition I assumed) $N^3 = k^3 n^3$ so it needs to be the former (i.e what is written).

Comment: OK, so we have $N=kn$... So, k is the ratio of the large partition count to the small partition count... so... I still think it would be helpful to get the specific definition from the textbook...

Comment: I edited it in (it would be good if the poster confirms)

Comment: @JohnA. I'm not so sure... Each of the $N^3$ "boxes" starts off with one ball (per OP's quotation). So there are $N^3$ balls. $k$ seems to just be the ratio of the large partition number $N$ to the small partition number $n$. The $n$ are subdivision within a single large partition... so... I really think it is still not clear...

Comment: I might agree, I tried to do it with the numbers given and I get $1.5\times10^{25}$ as the power which doesnt match the author...

Comment: I don't think my question can be considered a "homework-like question" or a "check-my-work question."
The physical sense of the situation is clear: Professor Penrose means that the number of configurations of the system 
"disordered" is extraordinarily greater than the number of configurations of the "ordered" system.
The point here is that Professor Penrose quantifies the 2 situations by providing 2 numbers that I am unable to verify.
Therefore I asked if anyone could suggest a way by which I could reproduce the result presented in the book.
If this question is not relevant I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: the question was edited and it makes this answer slightly imprecise.**

**Answer to First question:**

In each of all $n^3$ boxes we need $k^3/2$ blue and $k^3/2$ red particles exactly. With a total of $\frac{N^3}{2}$ red and  $\frac{N^3}{2}$ blue balls total, we have that for the first box we have $$\big(\frac{N^3}{2}\big) \text{Choose }\big(\frac{k^3}{2}\big)$$ possibilities for the red and same for the blue balls. For the next of the $n$ boxes we have

$$\big(\frac{N^3}{2}-\frac{k^3}{2}\big) \text{Choose }\big(\frac{k^3}{2}\big) $$
for the blue and also for the red. If we multiply all of these up we have
$$\text{Possible states} = \Big[ \prod_{j=0}^{\frac{N^3}{k^3}-1}\big(\frac{N^3}{2}-\frac{jk^3}{2}\big) \text{Choose }\big(\frac{k^3}{2}\big) \Big]^2$$
where the square is because its the same product for the reds and the blues. Explicitly,

$$\sqrt{\text{Possible states}} =  \prod_{j=0}^{n^3-1}\frac{\big(\frac{N^3}{2}-\frac{jk^3}{2}\big)!}{\big(\frac{N^3}{2}-\frac{(j+1)k^3}{2}\big)!\big(\frac{k^3}{2}\big)!} $$
We can take the $k$ dependent term out
$$\sqrt{\text{Possible states}} =  \Big(\frac{1}{\big(\frac{k^3}{2}\big)!}\Big)^{n^3}\prod_{j=0}^{n^3}\frac{\big(\frac{N^3}{2}-\frac{jk^3}{2}\big)!}{\big(\frac{N^3}{2}-\frac{(j+1)k^3}{2}\big)!} $$
Now, we can see that there are cancellations (explicitly):
$$\sqrt{\text{Possible states}} =  \Big(\frac{1}{\big(\frac{k^3}{2}\big)!}\Big)^{n^3}\frac{\big(\frac{N^3}{2}\big)!}{\big(\frac{N^3}{2}-\frac{k^3}{2}\big)!} \frac{\big(\frac{N^3}{2}-\frac{k^3}{2}\big)!}{\big(\frac{N^3}{2}-\frac{2k^3}{2}\big)!}\ldots\frac{\big(\frac{N^3}{2}-\frac{n^3k^3}{2}\big)!}{\big(\frac{N^3}{2}-\frac{(n^3)k^3}{2}\big)!}$$
The only remaining terms are
$$\sqrt{\text{Possible states}} =  \Big(\frac{1}{\big(\frac{k^3}{2}\big)!}\Big)^{n^3}\big(\frac{N^3}{2}\big)!$$
where we used $N = nk$. Take $\log$ of both sides,
$$\ln \text{Possible states} = 2\ln{(N^3/2)!}-2n^3 \ln{(k^3/2)!}$$
Use Sterling's approximation
$$\ln \text{Possible states} \approx N^3\ln{\frac{N^3}{2}}-N^3-n^3\big(k^3\ln{\frac{k^3}{2}}-k^3\big)$$
Simplify
$$\ln \text{Possible states} \approx 3N^3\ln{\frac{N}{k}}$$

We can put this into [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=3*10%5E24+*+log%2810%5E8%2F10%5E3%29) and we get
$$\ln{\text{Possible states}} \approx 3×10^{25}$$
where if written as a power of $10$ is
$$\log_{10} \text{Possible states} \approx 1.5\times 10^{25}$$
This is not exactly what he got for the power but its off by a factor of 2 (which is a lot considering its a $\log$). Anyway, this is my take on it. A more precise Sterling's approximation yields
$$\log_{10} \text{Possible states} \approx 1.91\times 10^{25}$$
which is much closer.

After looking at the text, he didn't assume that the balls were exactly 1 to 1 ratio which explains why we have less microstates than he does.